# variable with file scope in C without static keyword

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks

In the below code, I removed the word extern from variable declaration for var10 in file2.c I was expecting that the variable var10 in two files are independent of each other and both have file scope when extern is not used in one of the files. But the result is 10 and 34 instead of 10 and 10 as I was expecting. So we cannot have a variable with file scope without using static keyword? Why we do not get multiple definition error in case scope of both the variables is same? I use codeblcoks+mingw

**file1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int var10;

int main (void)
{
    var10=10;
    printf("Var10 before function call=%d\n",var10);
    var10TestFunc2();
    printf("Var10 after function call=%d\n",var10);
}
```

**file2.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int var10;
void var10TestFunc2(void)
{
    var10 = 34;
}
```

Comment: 'definition' vs 'declaration'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables without static have global scope by default. Here you have defined the the same variable(without initialisation). One is considered as the definition and the other as declaration by the compiler.

If you initialize the variable with two different values in the definitions itself. It will cause linker error.

Comment: This is not about scope, but linkage. Both are _tentative definitions_. Using an initialiser make a tentative a normal definition, thus the error if you have two files with normal definitions for the same name. (Note: it makes no difference whether the initialisers differ or not).